# What is the correct way to remesh?

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to remesh multiple merged objects into one mesh for sculpting. I've tried to do this with Blender's built-in remesh function, but it didn't work as I wanted. After the remesh, the shape had changed a lot, this visible the best around the short parts of the mesh. On the image, the left one is the original (converted from a curve) and the right one is the remeshed version.

Is there any way to preserve the mesh boundary and keep the shape after remesh? Or if it isn't possible what else can I do?

[image]

Comment: did you try increasing the number of faces when doing the QuadriFlow remesh?

Comment: What is the purpose of the remesh? Are you trying to reduce the amount of geometry? If so, you might find more success with a decimate modifier.

Comment: @Sanbaldo I used Voxel mode to remesh, with QuadriFlow it didn't merge my separated meshes into one.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett As I mentioned I merged multiple objects into one, but these are still separated meshes, just now as one object. With the remesh, I'd like to merge the mesh vertices for sculpting.

Comment: Consider a union boolean.

Comment: Have you smoothed the right one? If the result is still not good, maybe delete this part and recreate a clean topology with extrusions?

Comment: @AllenSimpson That would be a very good alternative solution, but where the two separated mesh would merge there are not enough vertices. I've tried to add a subdivision surface modifier and it was kinda good but with it, I got a lot of unnecessary vertices for the other parts of the mesh too, where it doesn't require. Any idea for that?

Comment: @moonboots I don't really understand what do you mean by the "Have you smoothed the right one?" question. Recreate the topology manually won't be good, the mesh aimed for a high poly one. In the image, the mesh is low poly only for the best illustration of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case **Decimate modifier** will be the best option for you considering that the remesh modifier changes the overall shape of your mesh , to reduce the amount of your geometry decimation can be best
Or if you want to stick with the Remesh modifier  you can increase the amount of voxel data to preserve the mesh shape

Comment: Remeshing doesn't change the overall shape, mainly it changes the small parts of the mesh, the rest of it doesn't change that much except the edge flow.

I don't know why would it be good to reduce the amount of vertices.

Comment: I don't want to stick with the remesh modifier, I'm open to everything that can solve my problem, but I don't think so the Decimate modifier would be my solution.

I reduced my voxel size to get more vertices for the small parts, but it's still not enough, the other parts of the mesh I got way more than it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no perfect one-click solution to remesh. Any built-in way comes with its disadvantages. For sculpting, usually the voxel remesher in the mesh data tab is the best option, since for sculpting we don't care that much about optimized geometry, just the general shape and enough resolution to sculpt on.

Other options are the decimate modifier as mentioned above (though that would be bad for sculpting, because *you actually do want high density in your mesh* for that), data remesh with quadriflow (usually voxel is preferable, but quadriflow *may* work better for you) or the remesh modifier.
To preserve the pointiness of your model, the *sharp* option of the remesh modifier might work.

If none of those work to your satisfaction, unfortunately there is usually just the hard way of doing it by hand (though usually you would do that *after* sculpting, because as mentioned, during sculpt the main point is to have enough density, not beautiful topology)

I find [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM) quite good for manual retopology.